# MetaMask problem showing in developer option's console

Tags: metamask

whenever I click to inspect a site and open the console...
I see this message:-
MetaMask: MetaMask will soon stop reloading pages on network change.
For more information, see: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#ethereum-autorefreshonnetworkchange
Set 'ethereum.autoRefreshOnNetworkChange' to 'false' to silence this warning.

MetaMask is not installed in the browser. I am using the Brave browser.
How can I stop this?

Answer (score 1):

Metamask comes included in Brave Browser. Go to main menu -> extensions and you will see "Crypto Wallets" which is the built-in version of Metamask that comes pre-installed in Brave. From that screen, you can disable it by using the switch near the name of the extension.

Edit: I just disabled mine and verified that the warning goes away once disabled.